# Showing that $R = \{ \pm(e_i-e_j) : 1 \leq i < j \leq l+1\}$ is a root system

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $e_i$ be the standard unit basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^{l+1}$

I'm trying to show that the $R = \{ \pm(e_i-e_j) : 1 \leq i < j \leq l+1\}$ is a root system for $E = spanR = \{ \Sigma \alpha_i e_i : \Sigma \alpha_i = 0\}$

I'm struggling to show that given $\alpha \in R$, we have that the reflection about the hyperplane normal to $\alpha$ permutes the elements of $R$. The reflection operator of $\alpha$ is denoted $s_\alpha$.

We have that $s_\alpha(\gamma) = \gamma - 2\frac{(\gamma,\alpha)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}\alpha$.

My calculations have not been working out. Can somebody help me with this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v_{ij} = e_i - e_j$. We find that
$$
s_{v_{ij}}\left(\sum_k \alpha_k e_k \right) = \alpha_j e_i + \alpha_i e_j + \sum_{k \notin\{i,j\}} \alpha_k e_k.
$$
From there, I think it should be clear that $s_{v_{ij}}$ indeed permutes the elements of $R$.

---

With that established, we find the following: if $\{i,j\},\{p,q\}$ are disjoint,
$$
s_{v_{ij}} v_{pq} = v_{pq} \in R.
$$
If $p = i$ and $q \notin \{i,j\}$, we have
$$
s_{v_{ij}} v_{pq} = s_{v_{ij}} v_{iq} = v_{jq} \in R.
$$
Since $s_{v_{ij}} = s_{v_{ji}}$ and $v_{pq} = -v_{qp}$, all cases where there is one common index are similar to this one. Finally, if $\{i,j\} = \{p,q\}$, we find that $s_{v_{ij}}v_{pq} = -v_{pq} \in R$.

In each case, $s_{v_{ij}}$ takes elements of $R$ to $R$. Because $s_{v_{ij}}$ is invertible, the map induced on $R$ must be bijective.

Comment: So, you applied the reflection operator to an element of $E$. Would you be able to show me how you can apply it to an element of $R$ and that the output would be another element of $R$?

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa Sure, I'll edit my answer accordingly

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa See the latest edit

Comment: Is $s_\alpha(\gamma) = \gamma - 2\frac{(\gamma,\alpha)}{(\alpha,\alpha)}\alpha$ the correct formula for explicitly calculating the reflection map? I can't get the calculations to work out >.<

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa Yes, it definitely is. Maybe focus on calculating $s_{v_{ij}}(e_k)$ for the cases of $k = i$ and $k \notin \{i,j\}$. Do you get the right answer?

Comment: Well, I want to see that it permutes the roots, so I'm interested in $s_{v_{ij}}(v_{pq}) = v_{pq} - 2 \frac{(v_{pq},v_{ij})}{(v_{ij},v_{ij})}v_{ij} = v_{pq} - 2[\delta_{pi} - \delta{qi} - \delta_{pj} + \delta_{qj}]v_{ij}$.



In the case of $p=i$ and $j \neq q$ I believe this becomes:

$s_{v_{ij}}(v_{pq})  = v_{pq} - 2[1]v_{pj} = -e_p - e_q$.

Comment: @H I get that, but as part of the "debugging" process it'd be best to start with the simpler caclulation

Comment: For $k \neq i,j$ we have $s_{v_{ij}}(e_k) = e_k - (e_i-e_j,e_k)v_{ij} = e_k$ I believe

Comment: Right, and for $k = i$ we get
$$
s_{v_{ij}} e_i = e_i -  (e_i - e_j) = e_j.
$$
any disagreement there?

Comment: $s_{v_{ij}}(e_i) = e_i - 2(e_i,e_i-e_j)v_{ij} = e_i - 2v_{ij} = e_i - 2(e_i-e_j) = -e_i - 2e_j$. 

Hmm.. It seems I am not calculating this correctly.

Comment: @H You're getting the denominator wrong.
$$
-2\cdot \frac{(e_i,e_i - e_j)}{(e_i - e_j,e_i - e_j)}v_{ij} = -2\frac{1}{2}v_{ij} = -v_{ij}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your patience

Comment: @H Glad to help!